# Column header as row value

Tags: r, nlp, docx

I am extracting tables from word documents using the docxtractr package, but one of my tables is not turning out well.

After extraction, it looks like

| Column A | Column A value |
| --- | --- |
|  | Column B value |
| Column C | Column C value |

and I want it to look like

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column A value | Column B value | Column C value |

Is there a way to format table 1 to table 2?

Or perhaps a better way of extracting the values/tables from the word document?

TIA

I'm still looking for solutions.

Comment: How would you impute the header for Column B? They're not literally named "Column A", "Column B" ... are they? As for pivoting from long format (table 1) to wide format (table 2), there's a couple of functions (I like `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` from package {tidyr}).

Comment: I would want to include a custom header for column B as part of the table manipulation

Comment: If your data just looks like that, it looks like you just want to transpose it with `t()` or something similar, and then fix the issues. A better option would be to import it properly, but figuring that out would be a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **d** is your table ...

```
## create example table:
d <- structure(list(Var1 = c("Column A", NA, "Column C"), Var2 = c("Column A value", 
"Column B value", "Column C value")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))
```

```
> d
      Var1           Var2
1 Column A Column A value
2     <NA> Column B value
3 Column C Column C value
```

... you can use {dplyr} and {tidyr} to substitute missing column names and reshape to wide format like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d |>
mutate(Var1 = ifelse(is.na(Var1), paste0('Column_', row_number()), Var1)) |>
pivot_wider(names_from = Var1, values_from = Var2)
```

```
  `Column A`     Column_2       `Column C`    
  <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
1 Column A value Column B value Column C value
```

You might need to set the `header` argument to `FALSE` upon import: `docx_extract_tbl(..., header = FALSE, ...)`